# VSCode Intellisense with PyQt5

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyqt, pyqt5, intellisense

Is there a way to improve Intellisense for PyQt5 in VSCode? It doesn't show any of the enums like QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft, and it says `"pyqtProperty" is not defined`. I can still run the code just fine, but it would be nice if it could autocomplete that stuff.

I have installed pyqt5-stubs, but that doesn't help.

Comment: That is because they are defined as AlignmentFlags.  Type `Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft`  they are all there

Comment: Hmm, ok. Doesn't really help me though, because I'm still probably going to type the first one. Also why does the pyqtProperty problem happen? If I do `from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtProperty`, it doesn't underline it in yellow, but if I do `from PyQt5.QtCore import *` it does.

Comment: That one I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an existing problem that has not yet been solved.

Please continue to follow [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/python-type-stubs/issues/205) on github.